# When can I stop drawing costly samples?

Tags: nonparametric, experiment-design, sample-size, sequential-analysis

I'm running (costly) experiments and I need to decide when to stop gathering samples. Is the following approach correct?

I'm testing a software package for performance: I measure the time it takes for the software to give me a specific answer.  Depending on random changes in the data, the solution time will vary, sometimes a lot.  I want to investigate whether a particular change in the software tends to give me better performance or not.  But I don't want to spend more time experimenting than is necessary (e.g. assume that each test takes minutes to run).  I don't want to run 30 tests on each side if I could reach the same conclusion with 10 tests on each side.

It seems to me that a more formal description of this issue would be :

- I have two random variables, of which I know nothing
- I can draw as many samples as I want from each variable, but drawing these samples is costly
- I want to stop when I know with some confidence that one of the two variables has a mean that's different (by at least 20%, let's say) from the other

I've read a bit about Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Kruskal-Wallis and other non-parametric tests, but my knowledge of statistics is pretty low.   I can imagine that I run one of these tests, see whether it gives me something, add a pair of samples (one from each variable), and iterate.  I'm not sure how that would ever stop if the two variables have the same mean, though...

So I wonder if I'm on the right track, and whether you could point me to references for this type of problem.

Comment: From the information provided, maybe it could be helpful to familiarize yourself with the concept of [power analysis and sample size estimation](https://www.rips-irsp.com/articles/10.5334/irsp.181/). However, I'm not completely sure, if in your case the increase in sample size or the increase in number of "experiments" is the factor driving up the cost.

Comment: You are looking for a *sequential* test.  Such experiments, although somewhat open-ended, tend to require fewer samples *on average* than a fixed-size experiment (which is why sample size estimation is not directly relevant, @Dom42). Your concern is appropriate: when the variables have the same mean, such a test could run a very long time.  The usual approach is to set a limit on the number of tests beforehand and, if that limit is reached, to agree that you will accept whatever answer currently looks more plausible or else to conclude you can't tell that there's a difference.